# Ubuntu 16.04 PGP Key Importing problems

Tags: 16.04, pgp

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. The only problem is that I cannot get them to show up in my Passwords and Keys application. Typing `gpg --list-keys` in terminal shows all the keys I've added but they don't appear in my PGP GUI.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between OpenPGP, PGP and GnuPG? Very likely you're not using PGP at all. If you _are_ using any version of PGP, it does not share a key store with GnuPG, so you'll have to import the key(s) separately.

Comment: I'm using Seahorse (GnuPG keys). When I go to import a key their information about their key comes up fine. When I click import it doesn't appear in the GnuPG key GUI. I think 16.04 is bugged.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. You're confusing several products and standards. There is nothing like a "GnuPG key GUI". If you want a proper answer, you should be much more specific what exactly you performed and which products (preferably including version numbers) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

No keys show up because the Passwords and Keys application (Seahorse) does not migrate gpg1 keys to gpg2.

You can do this manually:

```
gpg2 --import < ./.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Further reading:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1577198
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg2/+bug/1565963